# Block registration if form input doesn't match accepted values using Laravel's auth (5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this reference_id variable that I want to use to bar registration on my site. Basically, if you don't input a reference_id that matches correctly one value among a list (~5-10) values then I want to turn them away. Similarly to how if you only put TEST in the email field it stops you and says "Hey that's not a valid email!'.

Where would I put that logic in? I've pasted my RegisterController below as I think it should go there along with the email logic. I could easily make a variable and do something like

```
$rfid=reference_id
$list=array(list)
if ($rfid==$list) {
     allow
}
else {
     reject
}
```

But as you can tell even with that I'm not sure how it would work exactly or where to put it among the rest of the code. Any direction would be appreciated!

**RegisterController:**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'reference_id' => 'max:255',

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'reference_id' => $data['reference_id'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reference_id is present in the table you can use

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'reference_id' => 'max:255|exists:table_name',

    ]);
}
```

If there is an array

use `in_array:$array_name` for validation

For Proper Understanding of available Laravel Validation rule Refer:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists

Hope This Helps you..

Lets me know in case of any Query..

Comment: When you say "If the reference_id is present in the table you can use" are you referring to the list of accepted values? Or the value they input?

Comment: You might be having a table which has all the reference id.and if you want to check if the value exists amongst those value you can use exists

Comment: and if you are creating an array you can use the edited solution

Comment: @Albure table==database table

Comment: If you find the solution Useful.Accept the solution so that others to get benefit from the same.Glad to Help you

Comment: Running this method I received this error
https://gyazo.com/031d134f880d76a222e04cffa29d2643
arfids being the table name. WHOOPS STUPID ERROR

Comment: in arfids Database table is there a column with name reference_id

Comment: You need a column named reference_id in user database table which refers to the id column in REFERENCE database table..

so your exists statement will work

Comment: Yeah I incorrectly named the column and had to rollback that migration. going to test it now

Answer (score 0):

Use [`in`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-in) validation rule. Advantage of this rule is it's source independent and format independent:

```
$allowedValues = implode(',', config('my.allowedKeys'));
// Or:
$allowedValues = implode(',', Reference::pluck('id')->toArray());
....
'reference_id' => 'max:255|in:'.$allowedValues,
```

If you want you can also add [custom validation message](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-error-messages) for this rule.

Comment: What does the implode do? And I could pretty easily just create a new table in my database and load that with the accepted values. Could I then use this method to, in a sense, cross check accepted values?

Comment: `implode()` here creates comma separated string from an array. If you're sure you'll always keep keys in a table you can use this method or `exists` rule. But I wouldn't create separate table just to keep 5 strings, I'd keep those in config instead.

Comment: I think I better understand this method. Essentially I am creating an array with the accepted values in it and then using the 'in' validation rule to check if the value they give is in the accepted values array? Is the 'my.allowedKeys' a reference to a potential database table?

Comment: It will start out as 5 but could potentially grow to many. So in the long run a separate table might be a good idea

Comment: If you're sure you'll never change the source, use `exists` rule instead.